# How to open Visual Studio Code on macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, installation, configuration-managment

I've just installed Visual Studio Code on my mac running the latest OS Catalina.  When I try to open from the apps cat, I get an error message that it can't be opened and needs to be upgraded.  because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.

Comment: Any reason you cannot upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass this protection mechanism:

Go to *System Preferences » Security » Open Visual Studio Code anyway*

Comment: This resolved the issue. I had performed this once before and forgot that is how Apple sets permissions on opening files.